# Selenium Webdriver java rootWebElement.findElements ignore sub-children?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

So here's the premise, my custom searcher is designed to navigate all children of a WebElement to find its child nodes.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.bing.com");
WebElement webElement = new WebDriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.TagName("HTML"));

webElement = webElement.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q"));
webElement.sendKeys("Gibraltar");
webElement = webElement.findElement(By.id("sb_form_go"));
webElement.click();

webElement = webElement.findElement(By.id("b_results"));

List<WebElement> elementList = webElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
for (WebElement webElement : elementList) {
  System.out.println(i + ": " + webElement.getTagName() + "-" + webElement.getText());
  i++;
}
```

Please note: The above is example code only to simulate what I am trying to do (The actual work is under non-disclosure and I can't post it)

**Example Output:**

```
0: h2-Gibraltar - Wikipedia
1: a-Gibraltar - Wikipedia
2: div-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar
3: div-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar
4: cite-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar
5: strong-en.wikipedia.org
6: strong-Gibraltar
7: a-
8: span-
9: span-
10: span-
11: div-
12: div-
13: div-
14: ul-
15: li-
16: div-
17: a-
18: img-
19: li-
20: div-
21: a-
22: img-
23: li-
24: div-
25: a-
26: img-
27: li-
28: div-
29: a-
30: img-
31: li-
32: div-
33: a-
34: img-
35: div-Overview
Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more


History




































See all sections
36: div-Overview
Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more


History




































See all sections
37: div-Overview
Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more


History




































See all sections
38: div-Overview
Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more
39: div-Overview
Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more
40: div-Overview
41: img-
42: img-
43: div-Overview
44: div-Overview
45: div-Overview
46: div-Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more
47: div-Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more
48: div-Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
Read more
49: p-Gibraltar (/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/; Spanish pronunciation: [xiβɾalˈtaɾ]) is a British Overseas Territory located at the southern tip of the Iberian Peninsula. It has an area of 6.7 km (2.6 sq mi) and is bordered to the north by Spain. The landscape is dominated by the Rock of Gibraltar at the foot of which is a densely populated town area, home to over 30,000 people, primarily Gibraltarians. It shares a maritime border with Morocco.
In 1704, Anglo-Dutch forces captured Gibraltar from Spain during the War of the Spanish Succession on behalf of the Habsburg claim to the Spanish throne. The territory was ceded to Great Britainin perpetuit…
50: a-/dʒɪˈbrɔːltə(r)/
51: a-[xiβɾalˈtaɾ]
52: a-British Overseas Territory
53: a-Iberian Peninsula
54: a-bordered to the north
55: a-Rock of Gibraltar
56: a-Gibraltarians
57: a-Morocco
58: br-
59: a-captured Gibraltar
60: a-Spain
61: a-War of the Spanish Succession
62: a-Habsburg
63: a-Great Britain
64: span-in perpetuit…
65: div-Read more
66: a-Read more
67: img-
68: div-
69: p-
70: a-
71: a-
72: a-
73: a-
74: a-
75: a-
76: a-
77: a-
78: br-
79: a-
80: a-
81: a-
82: a-
83: a-
84: a-
85: a-
86: a-
87: a-
88: br-
89: a-
90: a-
91: a-
92: a-
93: div-History
94: div-History
95: div-History
96: img-
97: img-
98: div-History
99: div-History
100: div-History
101: div-
102: div-
103: div-
104: p-
105: span-
106: br-
107: a-
108: a-
109: a-
110: br-
111: a-
112: span-
113: div-
114: a-
115: img-
116: div-
117: p-
118: span-
119: br-
120: a-
121: a-
122: a-
123: br-
124: a-
125: a-
126: a-
127: a-
128: br-
129: a-
130: a-
131: a-
132: a-
133: a-
134: a-
135: a-
136: a-
137: a-
138: a-
139: a-
140: a-
141: a-
142: br-
143: span-
144: br-
145: br-
146: a-
147: div-
148: div-
149: div-
150: div-
151: img-
152: img-
153: div-
154: div-
155: div-
156: div-
157: div-
158: div-
159: p-
160: a-
161: a-
162: a-
163: a-
164: a-
165: a-
166: a-
167: a-
168: span-
169: div-
170: a-
171: img-
172: div-
173: p-
174: a-
175: a-
176: a-
177: a-
178: a-
179: a-
180: a-
181: a-
182: a-
183: br-
184: a-
185: a-
186: a-
187: a-
188: a-
189: a-
190: a-
191: a-
192: br-
193: a-
194: a-
195: a-
196: a-
197: a-
198: a-
199: a-
200: a-
201: a-
202: br-
203: br-
204: a-
205: div-
206: div-
207: div-
208: div-
209: img-
210: img-
211: div-
212: div-
213: div-
214: div-
215: div-
216: div-
217: p-
218: a-
219: a-
220: a-
221: a-
222: a-
223: a-
224: a-
225: a-
226: span-
227: div-
228: a-
229: img-
230: div-
231: p-
232: a-
233: a-
234: a-
235: a-
236: a-
237: a-
238: a-
239: a-
240: a-
241: br-
242: a-
243: a-
244: a-
245: a-
246: a-
247: a-
248: br-
249: a-
250: a-
251: a-
252: br-
253: span-
254: br-
255: a-
256: a-
257: a-
258: a-
259: br-
260: br-
261: a-
262: div-
263: div-
264: div-
265: div-
266: img-
267: img-
268: div-
269: div-
270: div-
271: div-
272: div-
273: div-
274: p-
275: a-
276: a-
277: a-
278: a-
279: a-
280: a-
281: span-
282: div-
283: a-
284: img-
285: div-
286: p-
287: a-
288: a-
289: a-
290: a-
291: a-
292: a-
293: br-
294: a-
295: a-
296: br-
297: a-
298: a-
299: a-
300: a-
301: a-
302: a-
303: a-
304: br-
305: a-
306: a-
307: a-
308: br-
309: br-
310: a-
311: div-
312: div-
313: div-
314: div-
315: img-
316: img-
317: div-
318: div-
319: div-
320: div-
321: div-
322: div-
323: p-
324: a-
325: br-
326: span-
327: br-
328: a-
329: a-
330: span-
331: div-
332: a-
333: img-
334: div-
335: p-
336: a-
337: br-
338: span-
339: br-
340: a-
341: a-
342: br-
343: a-
344: a-
345: a-
346: a-
347: a-
348: a-
349: a-
350: a-
351: a-
352: a-
353: br-
354: br-
355: span-
356: br-
357: a-
358: a-
359: a-
360: a-
361: a-
362: a-
363: a-
364: a-
365: a-
366: br-
367: a-
368: a-
369: a-
370: a-
371: a-
372: br-
373: br-
374: a-
375: div-
376: div-
377: div-
378: div-
379: img-
380: img-
381: div-
382: div-
383: div-
384: div-
385: div-
386: div-
387: p-
388: a-
389: a-
390: a-
391: a-
392: a-
393: a-
394: a-
395: a-
396: a-
397: br-
398: span-
399: div-
400: a-
401: img-
402: div-
403: p-
404: a-
405: a-
406: a-
407: a-
408: a-
409: a-
410: a-
411: a-
412: a-
413: br-
414: a-
415: a-
416: a-
417: a-
418: div-
419: div-
420: div-
421: img-
422: img-
423: div-
424: div-
425: div-
426: div-
427: div-
428: p-
429: a-
430: div-See all sections
431: a-See all sections
432: div-See all sections
433: div-See all sections
434: div-
435: div-
436: div-
437: a-
438: span-
439: a-
```

I've found that this process also adds all sub-children to the said list.

How do I ignore said sub-children from the list?

(Sorry if this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it.)

Comment: Can add some of your code/html and what is the result?

Comment: Ofcourse you get all with this `.//*`. To get only child, without grandchild use `./*`. A single `/` will get first sublevel and `//` will get all sublevels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong `.//*`.

```
<father>
    <child1>
        <child2></child2>
    </child1>
    <child1>
        <child2></child2>
    </child1>
</father>
```

In this example will get all from `father` - `child1` and `child2`

To get only childs of an webelement without sub-childs(childs of childs) you need to use `./`

With `./` you will get only `child1`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> elementList = webElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
```

vs

```
List<WebElement> elementList = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
```

the "." in your xpath grabs all the childs.

KunLun is right.

Comment: webElement.findElements(By.xpath("//*")); - this is useless. will get all elements from  dom. He wants first level of child from webElement. He should use xpath `./*`